# Viewing aggregated data for MCC accounts after AdWords Data Transfer to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

I've added an AdWords Transfer in BigQuery, which appears to be working as expected.

However, I have multiple MCC accounts in my AdWords account and would like to see aggregated data for these and I can only see the individual accounts.

Is it possible to see aggregated data for my MCC accounts using the data transfer service in BigQuery? and if not, how would I go about setting this up?

Answer (score 1):

Each transfer config will load into separate tables.
You can directly reference the tables you are interested in, or you can use scheduled queries (currently in Alpha - https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1n4H54RLPPB0C5C9liBmVSUf-R6DRovu6eaWDhvuPYVQ/edit) to create aggregated tables on a regular basis.

Comment: Thanks @Tib51. So I need to create a transfer config for each MCC account and then combine them using scheduled queries (or some other way)?